# How to launch sparkEmmiter (created custom smoke.sks file) in the view? Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, emitter

I have created the **SpriteKit Particle Emitter** file `smoke.sks`.
[image]
I want to make this animation run in a `UIView`, however, it has no `addChild` method and I still have some errors...

*I have tried this solution:*

```
func addSmoke() {

    //spark particle effect
    let sparkEmmitterPath: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "smoke", ofType: "sks")!
    let sparkEmmiter = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: sparkEmmitterPath as String) as! SKEmitterNode

    sparkEmmiter.position = CGPoint(x: self.backgroundMaskView.frame.size.width, y: self.backgroundMaskView.frame.size.height/2)
    sparkEmmiter.name = "smoke"
    sparkEmmiter.zPosition = 1
    sparkEmmiter.targetNode = self
    self.view.addChild(sparkEmmiter)
}
```

2 errors:

```
sparkEmmiter.targetNode = self
```

**Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'SKNode?'**

```
self.addChild(sparkEmmiter)
```

**Cannot convert value of type 'SKEmitterNode' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'**

Should I also create SpriteKit View (`SKView`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solutions I have found.
We need to change the `UIView` class to `SCNView` and create `scnp` file for particles.

```
@IBOutlet weak var particles: SCNView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = SCNScene()        
    let particlesNode = SCNNode()
    let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem(named: "smoke.scnp", inDirectory: "")
    particlesNode.addParticleSystem(particleSystem!)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(particlesNode)
    particles.backgroundColor = .clear
    particles.scene = scene
}
```

**But** ... **Apple** did **removed** the ability to create **scnp** files.

The second step is to change the type of the file. Create `SpriteKit Particle File`

*(do not configure this created file, because you will have to do it again when you change the type, it will reset)*

Now, change the `Identity` type.
[image]